# WebSocket is closed before the connection is established - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to get action cable to work and I'm getting the error

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://cloud9workspace:3000/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I've looked all over google and can't find anything that works. I did add line 3 to my config.ru because someone on Cloud9 community said they tried it and it worked. It didn't work for me though.

```
require ::File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
Rails.application.eager_load!
ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true

run ActionCable.server
```

I am using a pro workspace on cloud9 but  I haven't seen anything that indicates cloud9 to be the issue. I've been stuck on this for a while now. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Working from the terminal you should be able to connect simply by running `telnet cloud9workspace 3000`. If that doesn't work, then the problem is not with your Ruby code.

Comment: I'm not sure about the features of a pro workspace, but are you sure you have access to the port 3000 in Cloud9?

Answer (score 1):

What about running ActionCable standalone server? Are you using puma?

Add `cable/config.ru`

```
require_relative '../config/environment'
Rails.application.eager_load!
run ActionCable.server
```

And start your server (on 28080 port):

```
bundle exec puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru
```